# ssrs master detail report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I'm fairly new to SSRS and I can't seem to find an example of a master detail report. I'm trying to create a report which has matrix control which has all the data from query 1, now I want to have it where if the user clicks on a column it displays another matrix control underneath the row of totally different data (query 2). E.g. A query of number of cars at a dealership for master grid, then if they click on a column that has a number of cars, it shows another grid underneath that row of type of cars at the lot. Is this possible, any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create the 2 reports separately - Parent & Child. You only need to pay attention to 2 elements: Parameter and Action. Make the "column" from your Parent as the parameter for the Child. It simply is about Passing a Parameter from Parent to Child.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your talking about. Would this be using grouping in the table control?